# How many bytes can nvarchar store in Oracle

Tags: oracle, byte

I have an nvarchar field in Oracle and I would like to know: how many bytes it can hold if it has a length of 178?

Comment: An nvarchar field doesn't hold bytes. It holds Unicode characters. Are you asking "What is the maximum storage required, in bytes, of an nvarchar(178) field." ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your `NLS_LANG` setting.

Check http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/ch6unicode.htm#g1008281

Answer (score 1):

[From the manual:](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#i45685)

> *Width specifications of character data type NVARCHAR2 refer to the number of characters. The maximum column size allowed is 4000 bytes.*